# How to handle cross site scripting in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to handle cross site scripting ASP.NetCore MVC.
In prior frameworks we have annotations like [AllowHTML] and [ValidateInput] .But seems these properties are missing in .Net Core. So please share the details of the option available in .Net Core

Comment: This is well documented: [Prevent Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Give https://www.nuget.org/packages/NWebsec.AspNetCore.Core/ a look as well, lets you define and control CSP headers.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-2.2

If you are using Razor with variables, you should be safe for the most part because *"the Razor engine used in MVC automatically encodes all output sourced from variables"*

If you are going to circumvent Razor variables, and, for example, use something like `@Html.Raw(someData)`, then you need to be sure that you sanitize whatever you are outputing as raw (unencoded) html. 
You can use a sanitizer like this one (which I use):
https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

These are the basic safeguards that will prevent most attempts at XSS.